# Taking down unconventional roller blinds

Tags: windows

I've watched about 30 youtube videos on this but they all have the conventional spring-loaded or wheel-based mechanism and I can't find the same things on my blinds (or maybe I'm blind??)

I tried taking off the cover on the front to get a better view but that wasn't possible as there are plastic end-caps that are preventing the front cover from coming out. Those plastic end-caps are also not coming out because they're stuck at the top...

I can't even find the manufacturer or brand on the blind anywhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In your first pic, it appears there are 2 small metal tabs protruding out above the valence. I'd guess that if you gently lift on these, you'll at least get the valence off, and that will give you an indication of how to get the whole blind down.

Comment: Can you get a picture of the cassette when the blind is rolled all the way up? The retaining mechanism is sometimes on the back on these, but we can't see it here.

Comment: Can you _gently_ pry between the spindle and end cap on the non-chain end enough to pop the spindle free? Is the axle on that end part of the end cap or the spindle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FreeMan had the right idea, the tabs were the key!

The tabs had to be pulled and rotated clockwise. Mine were stuck pretty hard, but after pulling it with all my weight it finally rotated.

Here are the pictures after I took it off.

[image: tabs on the ceiling]

[image: the blind with a horizontal track where the tabs fit]

Comment: You should accept your answer as the correct one.